# Rigid Body Simualation not working properly

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

When I place a cube upon another object(the rigid body type of the cube is active and the other object is passive), and start the animation, pressing Alt+A, the cube gets displaced as opposed to resting on the other object. How to resolve this? I've attached images describing the problem.

The first image is the one before hitting the play button and the second one is after.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to *Apply Scale* first, then bump up the *Iterations*. How does your *Convex Hull* look like?

Comment: Where can I find the 'Iterations'? Where do I check and let you know how the Convex Hull looks like? I'm sorry, this is the first time I'm doing rigid body simulations.